# problems with in_array ,returning false

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I hope you can help me with this awkward issue.
I am trying to get a certain value from all rows in a csv file,all works good until in_array().

CSV File looks like this :

```
Mach Vu,11-25-2012  21:32:39,row1
Mach Vu,11-25-2012  21:32:46,row2
```

I am trying to get last value from each row (i.e. 'row1','row2').

Here is my code :

```
$i = 1;

foreach($array2 as $key=>$value) {
    foreach($array2[$key] as $value2) {
        if($i % 3 == 0) {
           $array3[] = $value2;
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
print_r($array3);
echo "<br />";


if(in_array("row1", $array3)) {echo "yes";} else {echo "no";}
```

Array 3 is printing :

```
Array ( 
   [0] => row1
   [1] => row2
)
```

Thanks in advance for help ! All the best !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may solve it for you, while also trimming down your code a bit and drastically improving performance.

My guess is that in_array isn't working due to extra whitespace, thus the addition of the trim()

```
$search = "row1";
$col = 2;
$found = false;

foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
    if (trim($value[$col]) == $search) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

print_r($array3);
print($found ? "yes" : "no");
```

Comment: Awesome ! Thx so much it's working. Can you please tell me why in my code it wasnt working ? thanks again

Comment: It's due to extra whitespace in the CSV.  Adding the `trim()` eliminates any extra whitespace on the data.

Comment: I have checked white spaces many times and it was all good but I believe this was the reason. Anyways thanks again for your help. Highly appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

How about something simpler?

```
$s = "Mach Vu,11-25-2012  21:32:39,row1";
$parsed_string = str_getcsv($s);
print $parsed_string[2];
```

This will print `row1`. See the documentation for [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv).

If you are reading a file, then try this (from the sample at the [`fgetcsv` manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)):

```
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $array3[] = $data[2];
   }
}
fclose($handle);

if (in_array("row1",$array3)) {
    print "yes";
}
```

Comment: Well I am a php newbie so I will have to ask you what if I will have hundreds of rows like that ?

Comment: And the answer that I am looking for why in_array is not working properly in this situation ? thx for your help

Comment: Then use the second example :)

Comment: @IonutLaurentiu probably because you have non-printable characters (like a space or a newline) in your file. You should `trim()` the strings as suggested by @TheSmose